# Как правильно текстом оформить этот фрагмент из песни «Вчерашний боец» М. Боярского?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно текстом оформить этот фрагмент из песни «Вчерашний боец» М. Боярского?

> В который из дней мы станем слабей — устанем? Черту подведём, идти напролом не станем.

> В который из дней мы станем слабей — устанем? Черту подведём, идти напролом не станем?

> В который из дней мы станем слабей — устанем, черту подведём, идти напролом не станем?